# How to remove the text shown on the top of a bar chart?

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, achartengine

I need to remove the text on top of the bar chart i created can you tell me how to achieve it. I am enclosing the output i got with the text circled that i want to remove. I am using achartengine to draw the chart.

[image]

Comment: are those Ads? may be they come with the chart engine you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable those numbers in AChartEngine find the line that ends in:

```
...setDisplayChartValues(true);
```

And remove it. (Or switch `true` to `false`, but I think they aren't shown by default.)

---

This is a feature of the SimpleSeriesRenderer class, [`setDisplayChartValues()`](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/SimpleSeriesRenderer.html#setDisplayChartValues%28boolean%29):

> Sets if the chart point values should be displayed as text.